# Strange Errors after Upgrading Apache CXF from 3.4.10 to 3.5.6

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf, soap-client

I upgraded the CXF dependency of our webapp from 3.4.10 to 3.5.6.
The upgrade required no further changes, and everything runs fine in my IDE (Eclipse 4.27 with OpenJDK 17.0.4.1 and Tomcat 9.0.76 on Ubuntu 22.04.2).

However, when deploying the same webapp on the target systems (same versions of tomcat and Java on Debian 11), a number of errors occur reproducibly:

- HTTPS connections to some SOAP servers fail ("Problem writing SAAJ model to stream: PKIX path building failed") even though the required certificate was loaded
- a multipart response from a different server can't be read because javax.xml.soap.AttachmentPart.getSize() returns 0, even though the response payload is valid and not empty

Rolling back the CXF version fixes both problems immediately.

I can't find any significant difference between both deployments, local and target. Chances are that some subtle configuration settings are different, but I didn't find any.

Perhaps there is a version conflict with other dependencies (of which there are plenty) which surfaces only randomly.

What can I do to identify the root cause of this problem?